# The input string using sys.stdin is not the same using sys.argv?

Tags: python, stdin, sys

I have a small application that takes a string (a DNA sequence) and does several manipulations.

When I created this I uses as input this approach:

```
user_input = sys.argv[1]
```

So, if a type `python main.py TATA`  That works.

Now, I want to use this `echo TATA | python main.py` to do that first I have commented `# user_input = sys.argv[1]` (at the moment) and I have added this line

```
user_input = sys.stdin.read()

# and to see the input I have added

print(user_input)
```

When I type `echo TATA | python main.py` the input is TATA what is fine. However, for a reason I don't understand, this is not accepted by the python class of my application and the errors I got dont explain the reason.

I copied and pasted here the code of main.py until the line of the first error

Error 1:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/A/A/A/A/main.py", line 29, in 
print(DNA.length())

```
import sys
from clases.sequence import Sequence
from clases.read_file import Read_file

# The input:
# user_input = sys.argv[1]


user_input = sys.stdin.read()
print(user_input)



# To be able to get two type of input
# A sequence from the command line 
    # python main.py TATA
# A file.txt with the sequence
    # python main.py PATH/file_name.txt

if 'txt' in user_input:
    DNA = Read_file(user_input)
    data_loaded = DNA.load_data()
    DNA = Sequence(data_loaded)
else:
    DNA = Sequence(user_input)

# print(DNA.load_data())
print("Length:")
print(DNA.length()   # LINE 29
```

Error 2.

File "/A/AAtop/A/A/clases/sequence.py", line 46, in length
return len(self.DNA)
AttributeError: 'Sequence' object has no attribute 'DNA'

Line 42 to 46 of that script

```
def length(self):
        '''
        That returns the length of the original sequence
        '''
        return len(self.DNA)
```

Comment: this seems to be unrelated. whatever `self` refers to has an member `DNA` and that member doesn't have a length. The code you show doesn't show where you set `self.DNA`, but it's not the same as your top-level `DNA`. Also, the last line of your upper example is simply not proper Python; if only for the `.` at the end.

Comment: @MarcusMüller: Python `if` statements don't create their own scope.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica err, true. I was in C++ in my head. let me fix my comment.

Comment: With `user_input = sys.stdin.read()` , the string user_input ends with "\n". Could that be a problem? Test it with:  `b = sys.stdin.read() ; print(repr(b), type(b))`

Comment: You are right Demi-Lune I have got this ``` 'TATA\n' <class 'str'>```

Comment: I have added .strip() and all work perfectly. Thanks all